# C++ SDL Vector of Textures Storing NULL Objects

Tags: c++, textures, vector, sdl

I'm attempting to (re)learn C++ by making a top-down shooter game using SDL. In my game, I have created a `Graphics` class that handles all of the drawing, textures, etc.

The game is in its *very* early stages, and at the moment the `Graphics` class has a `textureList`, which is simply a vector of pointers to SDL textures:

`vector<SDL_Texture*> textureList;`

The `Graphics` class has an `int addTexture(const char* filename)` method, which is used by a `GameObject` to add textures to the `textureList` vector, and return the vector ID back to the GameObject, so that it can access its texture when needed:

```
int Graphics::addTexture(const char* filename) {
    SDL_Texture* tx = IMG_LoadTexture(this->renderer, filename);
    this->textureList.push_back(tx);
    return (textureList.size() - 1);
}
```

The `addTexture` method is called by a `GameObject` like this:

`GameObject player(10, 10, g.addTexture("player.png"));`

Later on, a `GameObject` will call an `updateGraphics()` method on the `Graphics` class, which uses the stored ID to draw a texture:

```
void Graphics::drawTexture(int id, int x, int y, int w, int h, int angle) {
    SDL_Texture* tx = this->textureList.at(id);
    SDL_Point* centre = NULL;
    SDL_RendererFlip flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE;
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.w = w;
    rect.h = h;
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(this->renderer, tx, NULL, &rect, angle, centre, flip);
}
```

From what I can tell, the `SDL_Texture*` taken from `textureList` and stored in `tx` is `NULL`, and I've read that this is because `textureList` is storing pointers to objects that become `NULL` once the objects are destroyed (after the call to `addTexture()`?).

I've also read about storing deep copies of the textures in the vector, but I'm unsure how to do that, as I only seem to have access to pointers to textures.

Any help or advice greatly appreciated - especially if I'm just going about this the wrong way!

Thanks,
Rich.

Comment: Have you tried SDL_GetError() to catch the possible SDL errors? Maybe there was a problem while initializing some of the SDL

Comment: Thank you! I printed `SDL_GetError()` and got `Couldn't open player.png`. I'd assumed the wrong working directory for the images!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I can tell, the `SDL_Texture*` taken from textureList and stored in `tx` is `NULL`, and I've read that this is because textureList is storing pointers to objects that become `NULL` once the objects are destroyed (after the call to `addTexture()`?).

No, that's wrong. Pointers are not magic, they don't change value by themselves anymore than other objects do. If `drawTexture` stores a non-null `SDL_Texture *` inside the vector, then it will still be there later, so your code works.

Note, however, that `IMG_LoadTexture` returns `NULL` if it encounters an error, and you don't check for it, so you might store an actual null pointer in `textureList` from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for this. I misunderstood, and it turns out there was an error with the creation of the texture.

Answer (score -1):

Note to future me...

The problem had nothing to do with the use of pointers to textures (as Quentin stated above), but was instead due to `SDL_Texture` not being able to find the image.

I changed the working directory in the build settings and everything works!

Thanks everyone for your help -- I knew it must have been due to a mistake on my part!

Comment: As Quentin mentioned it would be also helpful for your future development to check if the creation of the textures was successful by checking the returned pointer of the IMG_Loadtexture() so you will avoid crashes and possible errors.

Comment: "Note, however, that `IMG_LoadTexture` returns `NULL` if it encounters an error," Not finding the image is an error and `NULL` was being added to the `vector` because of this. Quentin's answer is completely correct.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've marked Quentin's answer as correct.